# how to force sleuth not send in single b3 header

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth

I'm using sleuth in my Spring Boot application for log tracing, and my application also send some messages via Active MQ, but when i see the message properties, it send the trace with a single b3 header.
how can i configure sleuth to separate the headers?

Comment: By default it sets the tracing context in separate headers. If you want a single b3 header you have to opt in with a property. So since you've already done it, just disable the property

Comment: I'm using spring-cloud-starter-sleuth 2.2.2.RELEASE and right now the default is a single header. what is the property that i can set to disable it?

Comment: Actually my bad, we always propagate the multiple headers (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/dfcc3223a57dc557c93bbfd983ddc967a56411c3/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/messaging/MessageHeaderPropagation.java#L40) . In which field do you see that single B3 header?

Comment: in "properties" on ActiveMQMessage, i see in the following format: b3={123456789abcdefgh-123456789abcdefgh-0}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default is not only better performance, but doesn't violate JMS header name rules. I would advise you figure out why you cannot use b3 single.

If you must use multiple headers, you can do something like this:

```java
@Bean Propagation.Factory customPropagationFactory() {
  return B3Propagation.newFactoryBuilder()
      .injectFormat(Span.Kind.PRODUCER, Format.MULTI)
      .injectFormat(Span.Kind.CONSUMER, Format.MULTI)
      .build();
}
```

Comment: because the default behavior is in a non Spring Boot application(send AMQ messages from Spring Boot to a non Spring Boot), which means sleuth doesn't support it, and i do want to trace in there too.

Comment: it's not that simple on a legacy code =] yeah the easy solution is just to crop the property, but wanted to avoid doing so

Comment: This works, but then it ignores any spring.sleuth application.properties you have configured it with.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the `spring.sleuth.baggage.xxx` application properties to work, then you need to wrap your propagation factory in a baggage propagation factory:

```
@Bean
public BaggagePropagation.FactoryBuilder baggagePropagationFactoryBuilder() {
    Propagation.Factory b3Factory = B3Propagation.newFactoryBuilder()
            .injectFormat(Span.Kind.PRODUCER, B3Propagation.Format.MULTI)
            .injectFormat(Span.Kind.CONSUMER, B3Propagation.Format.MULTI)
            .build();
    return BaggagePropagation.newFactoryBuilder(b3Factory);
}
```

See the javadoc on `TraceBaggageConfiguration.baggagePropagationFactoryBuilder()`